# show maximum value of one variable and associated variable in

Tags: r

**Data**

[image]

I want to show the maximum value of violent crime rates with the state. I am super new to this rstudio

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Also note that the rstudio tag is reserved for problems that have to do with the Rstudio IDE and not R

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! As a fellow newbie to R, I have the following solution which should work based on the variables in your screenshot.

```
crime[which.max(crime$Violent.Crime.rate),]
```

Best of luck